# Control-m Automation API - jobtype: web services

Tags: api, automation, control-m

Is it possible to use the ctrl-m Automation API when I have a Web Service as a job type?

I looked on the reference below and I don't see the option for web services
https://docs.bmc.com/docs/automation-api/monthly/job-types-932197928.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

web services are not supported yet in Control-M Automation API.